# PreparedStatement throwing SQL error 0

Tags: c++, mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-connector

I have this line of C++ code calling a procedure (this procedure works, I've tested it using phpmyadmin):

```
prep_stmt.reset(con->prepareStatement("CALL get_pass(?, @pass)"));
```

The code compiles fine, but on runtime, it throws this error:

```
MySQL_Connection::prepareStatement(const sql::SQLString& sql, int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency) (MySQL error code: 0, SQLState:  )
```

I've been looking into this for hours and I can't seem to find a solution - I guess its something to do with arguments but I'm new to Connector\C++ and all the examples I've seen just have an SQL command as a string. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does it throw when you exeucte `prepareStatement(..)` or when you try to execute the prepared statement with an argument? If the later can you include that code?

Comment: Also check out this old thread on MySQL developer's forum, https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,282191,282191#msg-282191

Comment: @JimmyNJ It throws when I execute that line I posted, which i find quite strange. I'll check that out, thanks.